# Sort (display) expense

Tags: display

I use the [Expenses extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/expenses) to keep tracking expense in my organization.
It was ok when we had only few entries. But now we have more than 40.
Is it possible to show newest on top and oldest on bottom...how do i sort out that?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried SearchKit?

Comment: No i did not. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I tried. But there is no option to display total amount.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for expenses using SearchKit, which will allow you to sort and display them any way you desire.

Note that each Expense is broken out into one or more Expense Lines. The Expense stores the date, type, status, etc. and the expense line stores the amount. Depending on how you want to display them, you can use either as the basis of the search and then add ("With") the other. Here is an example search of Expenses WITH Expense Lines:

[image: Expenses Search]

There is much more you can do with SearchKit, including grouping, filtering, and multiple ways to create a display, but this should get you started. For more general documentation on SearchKit, see https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/searching/searchkit/what-is-searchkit/

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I do not have with (optional) Expense Exepense Lines. Please see screenshot  https://ibb.co/K6xwMv0 Thank you

Comment: In your screenshot, I see that SearchKit is non-functional because something is wrong with your site's theme. None of the dropdowns will work unless you enable Greenwich or another Bootstrap-enabled theme.

Comment: I changed theme. But still there is no option "With (optional) Expense Expense Lines"  https://ibb.co/P4gyF4B

Comment: Curious, it seemed to work for me. Are you logged in as an administrator and do you have the `'manage expenses'` permission?